# Add font awesome icon to input type using :after

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use the `:after` CSS on an input field, but it does not work.

What am I doing wrong? Should I use another selector?

```css
._ght{
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
._ght input[type="text"]{
  width: 48%;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-size: 26px;
  border: solid 1px #94a6ae;
}
._ght input:after{
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f06e";
}
```

```html
<div class="_ght">
  <input type="text" name="">
</div>
```

Example Here:

[image]

Comment: `:before` and `:after` do not work with `<input />`. Only elements that can contain html content can

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? perhaps we can help you.

Comment: @Friday Ameh  Like this https://i.imgur.com/qga4TV7.png

Comment: @Stickers i have edit title

Comment: You can use :after on the `._ght` element

Comment: You gonna need a button for submit the search form by the way.

Comment: unless he was planning on adding an event listener to the input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @zgood wrote: `:before` and `:after` work with html elements only.

I would recommend using an extra `span` to display your icon after that input.

```
  <span class="addon"></span>
```

Without extra HTML add your icon to the `:after` element of your input container.

```css
._ght{
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
._ght input[type="text"]{
  width: 48%;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-size: 26px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #94a6ae;
}
._ght:after{
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      font-size: 25px;
      content: "\f06e";
      border: 1px solid grey;
      padding: 6px 4px 3px 4px;
      margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="_ght">
  <input type="text" name="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should solve your problem.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
        search{
                float: left; width: 800px;
                margin-left: 220px
            }

            .search input[type=text]{
                padding: 10px;
                width: 600px;
                border-right: none;
                border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
                float: left;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
                border-top-left-radius: 5px;
            }


            .search button[type=submit]{
                padding:9px 20px;
                border-left: none;
                float: left;
                border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
                border-top-right-radius: 5px;
                color: #888;
            }

 </style>


      <div class="search">
                <form id="search">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for Products and Services"/>
                    <button type="submit">
                    <i class="fa fa-search" style="font-size: 18px;"></i>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: this is a better solution but could use a better explanation.